# How to write a nested if condition inside a function to return 3 different values to 3 dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I am trying to create 3 new columns to my existing dataframe using the logic written on top of other columns in the same dataframe. I have a function which returns 3 values based on specific logic written in it. The function is as below.

```
def fun(a, b, c, d):
if "Category" in a:
    if (b == "some text" or b == "some text 2") and c.str.contains("Status1"):
        x = 1
    elif (b == "some text 3" or b == "some text 4") and c.str.contains("Status2"):
        y = 1
    elif b == "some text 5" and c.str.contains("Status3"):
        z = 1
else:
    if (b == "some text" or b == "some text 2") and c.str.contains("Status1"):
        x = 1
        x2 = 1
    elif (b == "some text 3" or b == "some text 4") and x2 == 0 and c.str.contains("Status2"):
        y = 1
    elif b == "some text 5" and c.str.contains("Status3"):
        z = 1
return x, y, z
```

Now I want to assign x, y, z to 3 new columns in my dataframe i.e. df['x'], df['y'], df['z'].

I tried to use zip as shown below but it gives an error.

```
df["x"], df["y"], df["z"] = zip(*df.apply(fun("Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4"), axis=1))

TypeError: ("'tuple' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Can someone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

The end state for me is to assign x, y and z to 3 new columns in df by performing logical operations on columns in df.

Comment: Can you provide an example DataFrame as input?

Comment: You're calling fun when you pass it to the apply function. So "fun" is returning a tuple (x, y, z) which the apply function then tries to call (hence the error). You need to pass a function to df.apply and not call it. i.e. df.apply(fun) not df.apply(fun()).